# How to add and use a stylesheet in a react spfx project

Tags: reactjs, sass, spfx

Im working on a webpart right now and am having an issue using icons from a sass package I downloaded.

I have some code that composes a set of classes that I assign to an  tag in the return statement of the render function. It generates the correct classes but obviously doesnt generate the icon when I use the webpart.

This is what generates the classes

```
this.conditionCode = this.props.data.day.condition.code;
this.conditionClass = "wi wi-wapi-";
this.conditionClass += this.conditionCode;
```

This is whats in the render statement

```
<i className={this.conditionClass} ></i>
```

And this is the import statement for the sass file:

```
import iconStyles from '../weathericons/sass/weather-icons.scss';
```

Obviously its not working but i dont know how else to do this. I know about the method where you reference styles using:

```
{styles.somestyle}
```

But that just wont work here since I need to compose the classes before using them.

Do I have any recourse here?

Comment: could you please share more details? is composite class name rendered on you page or custom class is missing <i className="wi wi-wapi-<code>"></i>

You can use "import './YourCustomStyle.css';" to reference your custom style

Comment: Sorry, I should have put in that I’m already using an import statement at the top of the file to import the scss file. And the composite class name is rendered properly, as is the <I> tag. They’re present in the page HTML, but there is no icon.

Comment: Then I am suspecting it may be because of class name not matching, you have to inspect and compare it from html element and class name on your custom style file

Comment: I dont disagree that that is my problem. I just don’t know how to link a css or sass sheet in an SPFx react project any other way. And the way I’m doing it isn’t working.

Answer (score 0):

First Import SASS classes -
import * as w from '../weathericons/sass/weather-icons.scss';

Allocate the classes in JSON Format -

this.conditionClass = { w.wi, w.wi-wapi };

Then render using -

<i className={ this.conditionClass } >